# How can I check for code blocks in my controls collection in ASP.net?

Tags: asp.net, controls

I am working on a method in my base page that throws the "The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks" message (and it's true, some of my pages have code blocks in the control I am trying to modify).

Is there a way for me to programmatically determine if this is the case myself? I tried iterating through the controls collection, but it didn't seem to state anything that I could use.

As background: the method is adding an error message control whenever certain exceptions are thrown. What I am doing as a workaround is to add the error message to the parent of the previously targeted control, because the way that these pages are generally written. I'd like to keep the natural layout of the error message if possible, so I want to check for the trigger that indicates codeblocks are in play, and only then do my workaround.